# Windows 8 RichEditBox - How to change the default line spacing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How do you change the line spacing of a RichEditBox for a Windows Store App with C#/XAML?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/010dee54-f8e7-41c6-9c0f-beecb95fa084) can help you but basicly Rob Caplan suggests:

```
MyEditBox.Document.GetDefaultParagraphFormat().SetLineSpacing();
```